# ItemCommand not working with repeater and few events

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, itemcommand

I get a repeater with 3 radio button (grouped in 3 rows by GroupName property) and triggered (per each radio button). My problem is coming when I add a HiddenField to the repeater column and I want to reach this HiddenField through ItemCommand event.

The ItemCommand event is not raising...

(LinkButton click event is working as well)

(If a set CheckedChanged event of radio button they are working fine, but They are not helping because I need to reach the HiddenField)

*This my code:*

**CSHTML**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterImages" OnItemDataBound="repeaterImages_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEliminarImagen" runat="server" OnClick="lnkEliminarImagen_Click" CausesValidation="false"><i class="fa fa-times" ></i></asp:LinkButton>
    <span>
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionado" Text='Logo 0' GroupName="nombreLogo" /><br />
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoApp" Text='Logo 1' GroupName="nombreLogoApp" /><br />
          <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco" Text='Logo 2' GroupName="nombreLogoAppBlanco" />
          <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdLogoId" Value='<%#Eval("id").ToString()%>' />
       </span>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

**JS**

> for simulating GroupName behaviour. Avoiding to have more than one
>   radio button checked per row

```
<script>
    function SetUniqueRadioButton(text, current) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {

            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i]

            if ((elm.type == 'radio') && (elm.value == text)) {
                elm.checked = false;
            }
        }
        current.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

**CS**

```
    protected void repeaterImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionado = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionado");
                RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionadoApp = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionadoApp");
                RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco");

                string script = "SetUniqueRadioButton('rbLogoSeleccionado',this)";
                string scriptApp = "SetUniqueRadioButton('rbLogoSeleccionadoApp',this)";
                string scriptAppBlanco = "SetUniqueRadioButton('rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco',this)";

                rbLogoSeleccionado.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
                rbLogoSeleccionadoApp.Attributes.Add("onclick", scriptApp);
                rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco.Attributes.Add("onclick", scriptAppBlanco);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PIPEvo.Log.Log.RegistrarError(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I tried:

- Surrounding the radio buttons by LinkButton (and use Click and Command event... None is raising...). *It Didnt work.*
- Define the ItemCommand as usual (trick CauseValidation="false" as well). *It didnt work.* (1)
- Setting the link between linkbutton and his function event programatically (as radio button). *It didnt work.*

***ITEMCOMMAND CODE (1)***

**CSHTML**

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterImages" OnItemDataBound="repeaterImages_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="repeaterImages_ItemCommand">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEliminarImagen" runat="server" OnClick="lnkEliminarImagen_Click" CausesValidation="false"><i class="fa fa-times" ></i></asp:LinkButton>
        <span>
              <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkbtnbtn" OnCommand="lnkbtnbtn_Command" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("LOGO_ID").ToString()%>' CausesValidation="false" CommandName="prueba"></asp:LinkButton>
              <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionado" Text='Logo 0' GroupName="nombreLogo" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoApp" Text='Logo 1' GroupName="nombreLogoApp" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbLogoSeleccionadoAppBlanco" Text='Logo 2' GroupName="nombreLogoAppBlanco" />
              <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdLogoId" Value='<%#Eval("id").ToString()%>' />
           </span>
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

**CS**

```
protected void repeaterImages_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField id = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdLogoId");
        string idlogo = id.Value;
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case ("prueba"):
                string idid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
```

**IDEA I AM LOOKING FOR**

Associate each radiobutton to its image (through id) respectively.
When I, finally, submit I could do my stuff, knowing radiobutton (action I will do) and image (logo_id) specific

Comment: Can you share your "OnItemCommand" event code?

Comment: Can I know on which control's event you want to raise "ItemCommand " event?

Comment: @ZakiMohammed Second Linkbutton....

Comment: Then you should use "prueba" in the switch case. You have command name "prueba" and you are looking for "selecLogo" in switch case

Comment: Thanks @ZakiMohammed, my fault. Fixed it. No, that is not the problem... Repeater is getting crazy trying to launch different events. For the radio button I had to implemented them programatically and so on...